# Error occurring when I execute commands in Python

Tags: python, spyder

I have just gotten a new computer and I had to reinstall anaconda (python version 3.7.3) and I am getting the following error when I execute commands. There does not seem to be any specific commands that it happens with, I can't correlate it with any one module.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py:448: DeprecationWarning: `input_splitter` is deprecated since IPython 7.0, prefer `input_transformer_manager`.
  status, indent_spaces = self.shell.input_splitter.check_complete(code)
```

After searching online, it seems like one of my dependencies might be causing this.  At first I thought it was geopandas or numpy but i don't think it is.  I am relatively new to python so if anyone has any advice on how to solve this, that would be great.

thanks